# use jquery to animate/show divs while ajax loads more results

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a page which loops through multiple unique id's and, using ajax, loads information into divs which correspond to rows in a database table. Because there are quite a few divs that need to be created and each div contains a considerable amount of information, this takes quite a while. What I would like to do is animate/show each div once it has been appended to the dom, allowing the loop to continue appending/showing more divs as they are created.

My code looks something like this:

```
// loop section unique IDs
$.each(uniqueIDs, function(key, uniqueID)
{

    // call AJAX synchronously
    // append resulting information to page

    // show newly appended div
    $("#" + uniqueID).slideDown();

});
```

The issue I am having is that the animations are very inconsistent. Sometimes the first div is animated while all subsequent divs are just shown without animation. Sometimes all divs are just shown without animation. I'm sure there has to be a more rigorous way to do this...

**EDIT** I have been calling ajax synchronously to keep the divs in proper order (otherwise the divs are appended to the dom in the order in which they complete). I'd be happy to find a solution using asynchronous ajax calls which preserve the original order.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, so you need to do the sliding stuff in the callback of the ajax function, and you should probably not be using ajax synchronously anyway.

Comment: Doing lots of synchronous ajax calls for data will be so much slower for the user than doing them asynchronously. You should do it async and put the slideDown code in the success part of the ajax call.

Comment: If I run ajax asynchronously, divs are created out of order (that is, in the order that the asynchronous ajax calls are completed). Is there some way to avoid this, and then use the callback?

Comment: You could keep a list of the uniqueIDs and their status. Each time an ajax call ends you'd set the status of this uniqueID to complete or something like that. You'd then loop through this list to ensure everything below this uniqueID is shown, and if not then show it, up to the first non-complete ID. Hope that sort of made sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of [`$.Deffered`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects for each asynchronous call, and then pass it to [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), whose [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) callback will only fire when *all* deferred objects are resolved, i.e., when *all* asynchronous operations are finished:

```
var uniqueIDs = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var $deferreds = [];            

$.each(uniqueIDs, function (i, elem) {
    $deferreds.push(
      $.ajax({
        // options
      }).done(function (data) {
      })
    );
});

$.when.apply($, $deferreds).done(function () {
   console.log(arguments); // arguments will contain the result of each asynchronous call in order
});
```

Thus you can use that callback to animate your `div`s in order.

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KfTsD/)**.

Comment: If you have 100 uniqueIDs, wouldn't this cancel the first 90-something requests because of the browser's XHR limit?

Comment: In your demo, calls to `document.write()` are still out of order. Even if I animate the visibility of the `div`s in the proper order, they will still be out of order in the page dom... or am I missing something?

Comment: @user890857: Yes, but those are the calls from the `$.ajax` inside the loop. In the `done` callback of `.when()`, arguments will be in your expected order, i.e., arguments[0] will be the result of first uniqueId in your array, et cetera.

Comment: @user890857: Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KfTsD/. With this, you can make all requests asynchronous, and *still* guarantee order.

Answer (score 0):

Running AJAX synchronously tends to have that kind of effect on things, cause the browser is hanging and waiting for the request to finnish, and can't run animations in the mean-time. What you should do is something like this:

```
// loop section unique IDs
var queue = uniqueIDs.splice(0); // copy array
function runQueue()
{
    if(queue.length == 0) return;
    var uniqueID = queue.shift();
    myAjaxLoadFunction(uniqueId, function() {

        // show newly appended div
        $("#" + uniqueID).slideDown();
        runQueue();

    });

});
runQueue();
```

Ofc you could replace the myAjaxLoadFunction with jQuery function-calls, or your own function for loading wich takes a callback.

Comment: The issue I'm having with asynchronous ajax calls is that the divs are created out of order. Correct me if I'm wrong, but your method of running the ajax function recursively will still result in divs being created as they load and not as they are ordered in the array.

Comment: No, cause only 1 is loaded at the time (queueing), thus they will appear in the order of the array.

Answer (score 0):

How about have parent divs in your HTML with the spinning wheel loading image.
So something like this :

You may want to determine size for DIVs and style them before but overall here is what i'm talking about

```
<html>
...
<body>
...
<div id="div1"><img src="loading.gif"/></div>
<div id="div1"><img src="loading.gif"/></div>
<div id="div1"><img src="loading.gif"/></div>
...
```

javascript:

```
result = $.ajax(...)
$("your divs").each(function(index, value) {
  $(this).empty().append(result[index]);
});
```

Something like that, where $(this) is the div and the result[index] is your row you are getting from the ajax request.
Basically the .empty() function guarentees that your loading png will be removed and then replaced with the data you want.

Good luck.